# Saving files with python codecs

Tags: python, save, codec

I've got two examples of code, that are supposed to perform the same thing (process text files and save the result to an outfile).
However, this one doesn't work for me:

```
with codecs.open('outfile.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as outfile:
    for f in os.listdir(my_files):
        outfile.write(some_function(codecs.open(f, 'r', 'utf-8')))
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Whereas this works perfectly:

```
outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
for f in os.listdir(my_files)
    with open(f) as f_:
        text = f_.read().decode('utf-8')
    text = some_function(text)
    outfile.write(text.encode('utf-8'))
    outfile.write('\n')
```

Am I doing something wrong with python codecs?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe provide your error? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line...

```
outfile.write(some_function(codecs.open(f, 'r', 'utf-8')))
```

...opens a file object without passing any text. You'll want to tack on a `read()` to get it working, like this: `codecs.open(f, 'r', 'utf-8').read()`

Comment: Oh my god, that totally solved the problem! Thank you so much :)

Comment: now I feel so stupid for asking such questions :) I literally spent an hour trying to understand what's wrong

Comment: @DariaSmirnova Cheers. It happens to us all.